# How to add permissions to Azure AD apps with PowerShell

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, azure-app-configuration, azure-app-registration

I am registering an app to Azure AD using PowerShell（Microsoft Graph SDK）.
I would like to add API permissions to the registered Azure AD app.
I want to add it to "Configured Permissions", but it gets added to "Other Permissions".
I would appreciate it if you could tell me the cause and how to deal with it.
thank you.

When I executed the command below, it completed successfully, but when I opened Azure Portal, it was registered in "Other permissions".
I wanted to add it to the "Configured Permissions", and although I tried several things, it was not added to the "Configured Permissions".

```
$AppRole = $GraphServicePrincipal.AppRoles | Where-Object {$_.Value -eq "User.ReadWrite.All" -and $_.AllowedMemberTypes -contains "Application"}

$params = @{
        principalId = $servicePrincipal.Id #Service Principal ID
        resourceId = $GraphServicePrincipal.Id #Microsoft Graph Service Principal ID
        appRoleId = $AppRole.Id
    }
# command1
New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId $params.principalId -BodyParameter $params
# command2
New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignedTo -ServicePrincipalId $servicePrincipal.Id -BodyParameter $params
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to grant application permissions to your AD app and have them appear under "Configured Permissions" in the Azure Portal, you need to give yes to these permissions.
as u asked see code in powershell below

This will generate consent URL

```html
# Specify your Azure AD app's Application (client) ID
$appId = "your-app-id"

# Generate the consent URL
$consentUrl = Get-MgAppConsentUrl -AppId $appId -RedirectUri "https://yourredirecturi"
```

later

output the URL that is generated

```html
Write-Host "Consent URL: $consentUrl"
```

After consenting this, check the Azure Portal under the "API permissions" section for your app. The app roles will appear under "Configured Permissions."

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
Thank you for answering.Thanks to you, I solved it!

Comment: if this helped you can accept the answer so others with similar issue can be guided thanks.